# Meaning of ice pitcher

Tags: meaning

I saw that word from a novel 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain. 
And here is the sentence.

"He never stopped to take a look anymore - he just hove 'em in and went for more. Well, at last he could hardly flop his wings, he was so tuckered out. He comes a-dropping down, once more, sweating like an ***ice pitcher***, drops his acorn in and says."

Is the author saying 'ice pitcher' to describe how sweaty the bird is? Because I searched 'pitcher' and the dictionary said it is a kind of kitchen utensils.

Answer (score 3):

An *ice pitcher* is a pitcher containing ice or icewater.

[image]

In hot, humid weather—which we get a lot of in summer along Twain's Mississippi River—water condenses on the outside of the pitcher, so it appears to sweat.